# Dialogflow API connect

Tags: javascript, api, dialogflow-es

Can I connect my web application with Dialogflow API?

I want send http requests to Dialogflow api and get responses to my chatbot application. I tried with Web Demo but I want to build my own interface.

Answer (score 1):

The Dialogflow API is introduced in a few Google Codelabs, linked below:

Build Actions for the Google Assistant (Level 1)
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0

Build Actions for the Google Assistant (Level 2)
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/index.html#0

After finishing the level 2 codelab, you should be ready to handle incoming HTTP requests and provide the appropriate responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use api-ai-javascript library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/api-ai-javascript

This works for me:

```
 import { ApiAiClient } from 'api-ai-javascript'

 const client = new ApiAiClient({ accessToken: this.token, lang: this.lang});
 client.textRequest(text, { originalRequest: {} })
    .then((response) => console.log(response));
```

The example in the npm library didn't work for me as I had to add the { originalRequest: {} } parameter.